# How to user Django reverse URL with java script variable?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am using a button on my Django template, After click on the button it should open a link offering by `reverse url`( `template tags` ). I tried with the following code but it didn't work

```
<input type= "button" style="float: right;" value="Next Graph" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'reverse(graph_view)';"></input>
```

I know that some thing is wrong with the above syntax. What will be the right one?

PS: I don't want to use any external library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the actual template tag for this `{% url %}`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

**UPDATE**

It should look like this:

```
<input type= "button" style="float: right;" value="Next Graph" onClick="javascript:location.href = '{% url graph_view %}';"></input>
```

If it still doesn't work, you have some other problem. Create a new question and make sure post any errors and stacktraces you get.

Comment: What will be the exact syntax because i have tried with it *** <input type= "button" style="float: right;" value="Next Graph" onClick="javascript:location.href = "{% url host_list %}";"></input> *** but it didn't work

Comment: Did you use it with or without the single quotes, i.e. `{% url 'host_list' %}` or `{% url host_list %}`? *With* quotes only works in Django trunk, but can be used now for forward compatibility by adding `{% load url from future %}` before using the `url` tag. Otherwise, don't use quotes around the view name.

Comment: I used the both i.e. with quotes and without quotes. I think that the problem comes because of quotes. Would you please paste the correct syntax (full <imput>...)?

Comment: My answer below is exactly the same. I guess I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

'reverse' only works server-side, not on templates.

You should use template tags.

```
{% url 'graph_view' %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url.

Comment: Thanks for replying @dannyroa, i tried with it ***<input type= "button" style="float: right;" value="Next Graph" onClick="javascript:location.href = "{% url 'graph_view' %}";"></input>*** but it didn't work.

Is there any syntax error?